# how do i replace a jar present in tomcat lib directory with a directory consisting of all the .java files?

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath

my tomcat lib directory consists of a jar which i want to replace with a directory containing all the .java files contained in the above mentioned jar.
Will addition of that directory to classpath in setenv.sh solve the problem?
eg PATH=$CLASSPATH:$XYZ/folder/*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm interested to understand why you would want to do this...
The .java files are teh source code.

Comment: More `PATH=$XYZ/folder/*:$CLASSPATH` to be first on the class path. _For such a hack there should be a very good reason._

Comment: I'm not having source of the jar and have to make few changes in a file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to have *.class files instead of *.java

Comment: yes it should be .class files instead of .java files.I made a mistake while posting the question

Comment: @FahadSheikh
If you want to make some changes in the file then the best solution is finding sources. Also, be sure that license of the library is ok for your changes. 
However, changes in the source code of the library is not a good way, so maybe you can find another library with the functionality you need or investigate library you used deeper

Answer (score 0):

The **jar** file consists of all **already compiled** and packed up files. If you want to get the .Java files consisted in the jar file, you could decompile them, but it's not the best solution. You should rather find the source of the library (the jar file) or ask the maker of the .jar file to share it with you. There is no easy method of decompiling the .class files (consisted in the .jar file). It is possible, and you will get working .Java files, but the code will have a lot of strange blocks and things.

Comment: source of the jar is not available. Have decompiled the jar, where exactly should i add these .java files(or the entire directory containing them) and how(syntax)?

Comment: You should treat them as normal source files (put them where you put all of your source files) or if there is a lot of them, you can put them in another package (refer to Java docs).

Comment: If the answer worked, you should mark it as accepted, if not, tell us because that's how people get to know how to fix their problems

Comment: it didn't work as expected, I was waiting for a better answer. Meanwhile I extracted the jar(unzip), made changes in the required files and made a new jar which can be added back to the lib folder.